# Can You check where I have my error in implementing Recursive merge sort function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, mergesort, cs50

I've been trying to get this done for 3 days now, I can't find where I have something's going wrong even after using debugging tools many times. Worked for size of 2 array but for array of size 6 with inputs: 55,34,76,12,45,76 I got different values when printed array after sorting, my code is this:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void sort(int arr[], int beg, int end);
void merg(int arr[], int beg, int mid, int end);
int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("How many numbers? ");
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %i Element of array: ", i + 1);
        arr[i] = get_int("");
    }
    sort(arr, 0, n-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i   ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void sort(int arr[], int beg, int end)
{
    if (beg != end)
    {
        int mid = (beg + end) / 2;
        sort(arr, beg, mid);
        sort(arr + mid + 1, mid + 1, end);
        merg(arr, beg, mid, end);
    }
}
void merg(int arr[],int beg, int mid, int end)
{
    int sizel = mid - beg + 1;
    int sizer = end - mid;
    int* left = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizel));
    int* right = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizer);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizel; i++)
    {
        left[i] = arr[beg + i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizer; i++)
    {
        right[i] = arr[mid + 1 + i];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (k = 0; k <= end; k++)
    {
        if (i == sizel)
        {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if (j == sizer)
        {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (left[i] < right[j])
            {
                arr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[k] = right [j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    free(left);free(right);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `sort(arr + mid + 1, mid + 1, end);` is wrong. It uses a different base for the array but does not adjust the other arguments to match.

Comment: `for (k = 0; k <= end; k++)` is wrong. The elements to be merged start at `beg`, not `0`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks a lot! the thing about k is perfect and you are right, but about the sort(arr+mid+1,mid+1, end) why is it wrong ? I know different base but since I'm dividing my array into 2 sub-arrays (the first array should start from the beginning) and the second array should start from the element after first's array's last element, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You primary problem is that you're mixing up notations.  You can identify a sub-range by `start, length` or by `base, lo, hi`.

You have this, which has one line doing things one way, and the other line doing things the other way, but doing it badly:

```
    sort(arr, beg, mid);
    sort(arr + mid + 1, mid + 1, end);
```

You need:

```
    sort(arr, beg, mid);
    sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
```

That is using the `start, lo, hi` notation consistently.  As it stands, you're telling your code to access a long way out of the bounds of your array.  That doesn't automatically mean your program crashes, but it does lead to undefined behaviour and erroneous results.

You should create a 'dump array' function like:

```
static void dump_array(const char *tag, int size, const int data[size])
{
    printf("%s (%d):", tag, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This allows you to print arrays when you need to. Then, after the first recursive call to `sort()`, you put:

```
 dump_array("After 1st sub-sort", mid - beg + 1, &arr[beg]);
```

so you can see what you get there, and another after the second recursive call, and a third call after merg(). You might print in other places too (entry to the function is a good choice, too).

In this context, maybe you should use a different design for the function:

```
static void dump_array(const char *tag, const int *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    printf("%s (%d:%d):", tag, lo, hi);
    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++)
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Now you can write:

```
sort(arr, beg + 0, mid);
dump_array("After 1st sub-sort", arr, beg + 0, mid);
sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
dump_array("After 2nd sub-sort", arr, mid + 1, end);
```

#### Working code

This code seriously reworks the `merg()` function which had a number of problems in it.  It adds the instrumentation I recommended, too.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void sort(int arr[], int beg, int end);
static void merg(int arr[], int beg, int mid, int end);
static void dump_array(const char *tag, const int *data, int lo, int hi);

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("How many numbers? ");
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    assert(arr != NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %i Element of array", i + 1);
        arr[i] = get_int(": ");
    }
    sort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i   ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static void sort(int arr[], int beg, int end)
{
    if (beg != end)
    {
        int mid = (beg + end) / 2;
        dump_array("-->> sort()", arr, beg, end);
        sort(arr, beg, mid);
        dump_array("After 1st sub-sort", arr, beg + 0, mid);
        sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
        dump_array("After 2nd sub-sort", arr, mid + 1, end);
        merg(arr, beg, mid, end);
        dump_array("<<-- sort()", arr, beg, end);
    }
}

static void merg(int arr[], int beg, int mid, int end)
{
    int sizel = mid - beg + 1;
    int sizer = end - mid;
    int *left = malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizel));
    int *right = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizer);
    assert(left != NULL && right != NULL);

    memcpy(left, arr + beg, sizel * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(right, arr + mid + 1, sizer * sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = beg;
    while (i < sizel && j < sizer)
    {
        if (left[i] < right[j])
            arr[k++] = left[i++];
        else
            arr[k++] = right[j++];
    }
    /* Only one of these loop bodies executes */
    while (i < sizel)
        arr[k++] = left[i++];
    while (j < sizer)
        arr[k++] = right[j++];

    free(left);
    free(right);
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, const int *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    printf("%s (%d:%d):", tag, lo, hi);
    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++)
        printf(" %d", data[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

I tested with a file called `data` containing:

```
11
19
66
71
69
91
46
14
38
77
97
34
```

The first line, 11, identifies the number of entries; there then 11 random numbers between 10 and 99.  The output from running `ms71 < data` (ignoring the prompting for inputs — which looks goofy because the data read from the file is not echoed), the output is:

```
-->> sort() (0:10): 19 66 71 69 91 46 14 38 77 97 34
-->> sort() (0:5): 19 66 71 69 91 46
-->> sort() (0:2): 19 66 71
-->> sort() (0:1): 19 66
After 1st sub-sort (0:0): 19
After 2nd sub-sort (1:1): 66
<<-- sort() (0:1): 19 66
After 1st sub-sort (0:1): 19 66
After 2nd sub-sort (2:2): 71
<<-- sort() (0:2): 19 66 71
After 1st sub-sort (0:2): 19 66 71
-->> sort() (3:5): 69 91 46
-->> sort() (3:4): 69 91
After 1st sub-sort (3:3): 69
After 2nd sub-sort (4:4): 91
<<-- sort() (3:4): 69 91
After 1st sub-sort (3:4): 69 91
After 2nd sub-sort (5:5): 46
<<-- sort() (3:5): 46 69 91
After 2nd sub-sort (3:5): 46 69 91
<<-- sort() (0:5): 19 46 66 69 71 91
After 1st sub-sort (0:5): 19 46 66 69 71 91
-->> sort() (6:10): 14 38 77 97 34
-->> sort() (6:8): 14 38 77
-->> sort() (6:7): 14 38
After 1st sub-sort (6:6): 14
After 2nd sub-sort (7:7): 38
<<-- sort() (6:7): 14 38
After 1st sub-sort (6:7): 14 38
After 2nd sub-sort (8:8): 77
<<-- sort() (6:8): 14 38 77
After 1st sub-sort (6:8): 14 38 77
-->> sort() (9:10): 97 34
After 1st sub-sort (9:9): 97
After 2nd sub-sort (10:10): 34
<<-- sort() (9:10): 34 97
After 2nd sub-sort (9:10): 34 97
<<-- sort() (6:10): 14 34 38 77 97
After 2nd sub-sort (6:10): 14 34 38 77 97
<<-- sort() (0:10): 14 19 34 38 46 66 69 71 77 91 97
14   19   34   38   46   66   69   71   77   91   97
```

There is probably room to optimize so that the code does not recurse when the array to be sorted has only one element.

Comment: Thanks for replying and much appreciated.
When you said I should do this:
```
sort(arr, beg, mid);
sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
```
I think you mixed up something, the idea is to send first half of array and sort it first then send the second half and sort it, So the second half need to be started from where first half stopped arr[6] -> becomes arr1(0,1,2) and arr2(3,4,5) that's the basic idea, and about the function you wrote i couldn't get it fully i'm still fresh into programming so dump_array function you wrote is really very difficult to understand.

Comment: No — you are working with the same starting address the whole time, but using offsets to identify the sub-range to be sorted.  See the working code – it does the job.  There was fairly major surgery in the `merg()` function.  I don't like the pattern where the main merge loop contains code to deal with one or the other of the arrays has been completely copied — I think it is much better to have 3 loops as shown, with one of the last two never executing.  It avoids repeated testing.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, really. Just if you have time to go further and explain small things briefly to me, what I changed in the original posted code was the first comment that said change k to beg not 0, and your note of second call to sort being (arr, mid+1, end) only these 2 things solved the code totally, now I'm not saying I don't want to try what you typed (totally the opposite, I'm very curious too) but I want to understand it completely, It's my habit to understand before doing anything. what I want to understand is what's wrong with(arr+mid+1)for second half?

Comment: You could use `sort(arr + mid + 1, 0, end - mid);` (where I reserve the right to be off-by-one on the `end - mid` argument) which tells the function to sort the array starting at one after the mid-point using indexes 0 to a small number. By trying to use `sort(arr + mid + 1, mid + 1, end - mid)`, you're starting the work at `arr + 2 * (mid + 1)` which isn't guaranteed to be part of the array, and the access go even further through the array. It's pretty much guaranteed to be out of bounds for some of the work near the end of the array; it can be accessing the wrong part of the array earlier.

Comment: Thanks a million! even that is not enough, but thanks from the deep of my heart, wish you all the best in your life and have a great time!!! :pray: 